# Cretive SDK Image Editor UI not show custom, resizable text (WEB)

Tags: javascript, css, adobe, adobecreativesdk

I made one email app where I want to use Adobe Creative SDK for editing images and adding text over image. All works almost great but when I click on "text" button and trying to add new layer (Add Text) I not see anything. All options is there, no erros in console just text layer not show up and I'm unable to insert text over image.

Here is my setup:

```
var featherEditor = new Aviary.Feather({
        apiKey: '[MY-ID]',
        tools : ['text','crop','resize','color'],
        fileFormat : 'png,jpg,gif,jpeg',
        theme:'light',
        displayImageSize : true,
        onSave: function(imageID, newURL) {
            var img = document.getElementById(imageID);
            img.src = newURL;
        }
    });

    function launchEditor(id, src) {
        featherEditor.launch({
            image: id,
            url: src,
            cropPresets: [
                'Original',
                ['Mail App','600x600'],
                '4:3',
                '16:9'
            ],
        });
        return false;
    }
```

I also remove my CSS from this page and leave clean Adobe library and nothing chaged.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I find solution for my problem. I just add one CSS code:

```
#avpw_canvas_element.avpw_position_by_transform {
    z-index: 0;
}
```

This fix my layering problem and all work great.